# How to get a collection of data in Entity Framework using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have created a stored procedure which will return a set of data. In my case it is set of roles

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRoles]
@ID Int
AS
SELECT Roles.Role FROM Roles WHERE Roles.CustomerCustomerID=@customerID
RETURN 0
```

I am using Entity Framework to get this value to a variable like this:

```
var query = context.GetRoles(ID);
```

I am planning to manipulate this `dataset` and create a `list` of "roles" and return the `list`

But since I am calling the stored procedure and I am not writing the query statement here 
for example:

```
using (AdventureWorksEntities context = new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    string LastName = "Zhou";
    var query = from contact in context.Contacts 
                where contact.LastName == LastName 
                select contact;

    // Iterate through the collection of Contact items.
    foreach( var result in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Contact First Name: {0}; Last Name: {1}", 
                result.FirstName, result.LastName);
    }
}
```

How can I get the values that are in each result?

I can not obviously access the fields of the table in intellisense

What is the approach should I take on this issue?

Thanks In advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a FunctionImport in your EDMX model, and map the columns to an entity or a complex type.  To do this, right click in the EDMX, choose Add/Function Import, and select the Stored Procedure from the list (if not there, refresh the model from the database). Give the FunctionImport a name (eg: "GetRoles") and choose what it returns (in your example, a collection of Scalars of whatever type Roles.Role is.

Then

```
var query = context.GetRoles(ID);
```

will return an `ObjectSet<T>,` where T is the type you have mapped it to, that you can iterate through.

Comment: Please can you elaborate on this. I already have the database context whic I use to access the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot podiluska. I will Leave some more links on this for others who are new to this. Some Others have suggested this on Entity Frame Work extensions. But this works great. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx –